# Camel File Poller Skip Processed Files

Tags: apache-camel

We are using Apache Camel File Poller in our project and we are running into one issue.  We drop files into a directory and it processes it perfectly and transfers it to the correct directory.  If a file that is dropped into the incoming directory is too big, we have readLockTimeout and readLockCheckIntervals that will try to acquire lock if it's fully transferred, else it will retry every few seconds.  HERE IS WHERE OUR ISSUE IS.

Lets say I drop FileA(3gb), FileB(250mb), FileC(300MB) and the first lock that camel acquires is FileA.  Ideally, FileA is still being transferred into that directory because it is so huge!  So what camel is doing is it's trying to acquire the lock on it and fails and does it every few seconds, which is PERFECTLY OK.  The part that is not ok is that FileB and FileC are just sitting there waiting until FileA is processed.  What my question is how can i make the lock act SEQUENTIALLY.  What I mean is if it acquires the lock on FileA and it's still processing, it skips the file and goes to FileB then processes that.

Answer (score 1):

You should copy the files with an extension that is skipped by the camel file consumer[using exclude URI option] and afterwards rename the file. In this way you will completely avoid conflicts with Camel file consumer before the copy is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to reduce the [`readLockTimeout`](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) parameter value. Jvadoc (excerpt):

> Optional timeout in millis for the read-lock, if supported by the
>   read-lock. If the read-lock could not be granted and the timeout
>   triggered, then Camel will skip the file. At next poll Camel, will try
>   the file again, and this time maybe the read-lock could be granted.

So, when timeout occurs, Camel will skip the file and come back to it later.